# UIWebView Showing white part at top of the Screen

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am implementing UIWebView  in application but after load i can see the space at top and content is starting from that point[image]

Comment: Add top, bottom constraints may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO; //in ViewDidLoad.
```

ios 7 add 64px automatically for scroll view. (status bar and nav bar)